# Changing scale of UIView doesn't change size of objects inside of it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, scale

When i change the scale of a UIView, the objects inside of it, UIButtons and such things, don't change size. How do i make them scale up and down with a UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried modifying the autosizing parameters in Interface Builder's inspector view?[image]

Comment: How do i do that when i create it programatically?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124176/uiview-subclass-wont-autoresize